# Why doesn't LocalSessionFactoryBean implement getCurrentSession, meanwhile the instance of SessionFactory can invoke the method?

Tags: spring, hibernate, session, code-injection

This is my configuration for Spring Bean:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
```

And then I use it in DAO layer like this:

```
    @Resource(name = "sessionFactory")
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
```

At last it's where my question come from:

```
    public T getById(int id) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    return (T) session.get(clz, id);
    }
```

In all, my question is that:

In class `"org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean"`,there is no  implementation for `SessionFactory's` method -- "`getCurrentSessio`".

I traced `LocalSessionFactoryBean's` hierachy system through, but I didn't find the implementation for the method "`getCurrentSession`".

I'm expecting your answers, thanks very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A factory bean, as its name indicates, acts as a factory. Its role is to create a bean of another type. Spring injects the product of this factory bean, i.e. the object that the factory bean has created. A `LocalSessionFactoryBean` produces a `SessionFactory`.

For more information, read [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-extension-factorybean).

Comment: Implementation route is like this, but what's the concrete mechnism of this kind of method? Cause,usually,we get the instance as bean directly.And another question:in LocalSessionFactoryBean there is no implementation for getCurrentSession which exists in SessionFactory interface.

Comment: As I said, and as the documentation says, when you declare a bean that is an instance of FactoryBean, Spring invokes its getObject() method, and injects the result of this method rather than the factory bean itself. LocalSessionfactoryBean's getObject() method creates a SessionFactory and this Sessionfactory is what gets injected by Spring.

Comment: Got it, then I can say if almost all the Class whose class name ends with "FactoryBean" must instantiate the instance to be injected into Spring by the same method. But,as I said above,method"getCurrentSession" is declared in interface SessionFactory,how can the instance produced by the factory bean provide the implementation for the interface method? thanks!

Comment: What matters is not that the class name ends with FactoryBean. That's just a naming convention that Spring uses. What matters is that the class implements the [FactoryBean](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.7.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/FactoryBean.html) interface.

Comment: Yes,I know.I just talk about the convention.

Answer (score 2):

You don't see

> LocalSessionFactoryBean's getCurrentSession()

Its bacause from api docs [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/AbstractSessionFactoryBean.html#buildSessionFactory--)

> protected abstract SessionFactory buildSessionFactory()
>                                                  throws Exception

Build the underlying Hibernate SessionFactory.
Returns:
the raw SessionFactory (potentially to be wrapped with a transaction-aware proxy before it is exposed to the application)
and see [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/1.2.9/api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/LocalSessionFactoryBean.html)

> This factory bean will by default expose a transaction-aware SessionFactory proxy, letting data access code work with the plain Hibernate SessionFactory and its getCurrentSession() method, while still being able to participate in current Spring-managed transactions: