# How entity manager is injected from localcontainerEntityManagerFactoryBean

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, entitymanager

I was searching for how entity manager is injected into DAO classes when I configure LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean class in spring.

```
class OrderDAOImpl {

   @PersistenceContext
   private EntityManager entityManager

   //....DAO Methods...
}

<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">

.....
</bean>
```

From this bean, how spring creates entityManager.

I was searching the same reason for hibernate's session factory and I found [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22283376/why-doesnt-localsessionfactorybean-implement-getcurrentsession-meanwhile-the-i) that getObject method will inject sessionFactory. But same is not the case with LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean. Can some one please help me understand how this entityManager is injected in JPA?

Comment: Spring injects a proxy which delegates a call to a `EntityManagerFactory` to obtain a `EntityManager`. The `EntityManagerFactory` is the thing that is constructed by the `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`.

Comment: @M.Deinum you're right. `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` create an `EntityManagerFactory` that creates an instances of `EntityManager`.